# Realizar una consulta y obtener un arrayEloquent

Tags: laravel, array, eloquent

Compañeros favor me ayudan con el siguiente error que se me presento

```
$attentionForEvent = DB::table('attentionlistss')
 ->join('subcategory_attentions', 
            'subcategory_attentions.id', '=', 
            'attentionlistss.subcategory_id')
->select('attentionlistss.id',
               'number',
               'dni',
               'ingresado',
              'espera',
              'proceso',
              'finalizado',
              'user_id',
              'name as subcategoria'
  )->where('attentionlistss.id', 33)
   ->first();
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Comment: Muestra que pones en el `return` de la función

Comment: Estoy retornando $attentionForEvent;

Comment: Probaste `return $attentionForEvent->toArray()`?